Why would the self-hosted runner raise a warning about not being able to find the project file?
I maintain an old ASP.NET application I upgraded to .NET 4.5.2 several years ago. The solution is comprised of 9 VB.NET projects. This is an intranet application. The guy who wrote the app years ago, used Visual Studio to do the build and deployment to the server, so I've followed his pattern, but now I'm trying to get GitHub's Self-Hosted Runner to build and deploy to a server in our network. The Self-Hosted Runner raises a warning:

WARNING: Project file D:\actions-runner_work\FP_Timetrack\FP_Timetrack\TimeTrackSite\ cannot be found.

TimeTrackSite is the name of the project, and the folder, in the VS solution. Timetrack is the name of the solution. Here's the code snippet from the YAML to try and restore NuGet packages for the solution:
- name: Restore NuGet Packages
  run: nuget restore $env:Solution_Name

Solution_Name is equal to Timetrack.sln. There is a project file in the folder that is mentioned in the warning message. That file is named Timetrack.vbproj.
So, the NuGet Restore command cannot find the project file in the folder, but it is there. And the NuGet Restore can find the other 8 projects in the solution and restore their NuGet packages. I don't understand why the NuGet Restore command cannot find the project file in the folder where it's looking and is there. Please, someone explain to me what's going on and why NuGet Restore cannot find a .vbproj file where one exists.
